# Trying to use var as img src in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a react project and I have a situation where I need the src attribute for an img tag to be a variable. The relevant parts of the code look something like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// topics is already defined and is a js object

const allTopics = topics.map(topic => {
        url = topic['image_url'];
        return (
            <Grid item key={ topic['topic_id'] } item xs={4}>
                <div class='img-wrapper'>
                    <img id='topicpreview' src={url} alt="loading" />
                    <h1>{topic['topic_name']}</h1>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        );
    });

return (
<div style={{ padding: '0', margin: '0', border: '1px solid black', width: '100%', height: '60%', overflow: 'hidden', display: 'inline-block' }} text-align='center'>
                <Grid container>
                    {allTopics}
                </Grid>
            </div>
    );
```

The image path exists and points to a valid file and I've console logged the url to make
sure it's the same path. However, it doesn't find the image and ends up printing the "Loading" alternate text instead. I'm not sure what's going wrong, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share a sample URL with us?

Comment: I should've mentioned these are paths in my local directory. One path is: './../../static/images/piano2.jpeg'

Comment: if your images are inside the public folder the path or URL should look like this 
    `/image.png `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your problem.

We cannot use a local path in `img`, because it will be referring to your local directory (not your website's domain)

To fix it, you need to call like below code snippet if you're using Webpack

```
const image = require(url); //or const image = require(url).default;

<img src={image} />
```

You also can try to find your local image with this URL `localhost:3000/static/images/piano2.jpeg` (your port may be different)

Comment: I am using webpack. I tried the change you suggested and I get the warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression. Also, it says it can't find the url ''./../../static/images/piano2.jpeg''. I don't know if the double quotes are relevant to my problem.

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong, could you share your folder structure with me? Which component is calling that image?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/piano2.jpeg does return the correct photo, which is promising.

Comment: -frontend/src/components/Entry.js -> the file requesting the image. -frontend/static/images/piano2.jpeg. I don't know how to properly share my folder structure here, but is this enough?

Comment: the correct path should be `./static/images/piano2.jpeg` instead of `./../../static...`

Comment: Hey, I just solved it. It was a really weird error. For some reason, it requested the correct url i.e. 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/piano2.jpeg but i added a ' at the very end for some reason. So I used src={url.slice(0, -1)} to test it and it ended up working. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!